# jQuery fadeIn() fadeOut() are behaving like show() and hide()

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein, fadeout

So I have this jQuery code which I want to on hover a certain image, fadeout that image and fadeIn another that is in absolute position.

The problems is that the funcions are not fading, instead they are just showing and hiding the images.

**The HTML code**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <img class="image-without-color">
    <img class="image-with-color">
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <img class="image-without-color">
    <img class="image-with-color">
  </div>
</div>
```

**The jQuery code:**

```
$('.partner-logo-container').hover(
  function(){
    $(".image-without-color", this).fadeOut(250);       
    $(".image-with-color", this).fadeIn(250);  
  },
  function(){
    $(".image-with-color", this).fadeOut(250);   
    $(".image-without-color", this).fadeIn(250);
  }
);
```

Thank you!

Comment: can you make a fiddle or something like that so we can figure out what's going wrong?

Comment: `.fadeOut` and `.fadeIn` never work well together. Try using `.fadeIn` on one element with `.hide` on the second.

Comment: Could you add the relevant HTML to a code snippet with your script to demonstrate the issue?

Comment: @koby I tried your approach and didn't work out. I'm starting to think that maybe i have some kind of conflict here.

Comment: @Fran I will do it in a sec!

Comment: As you haven't made a snippet with a working demonstration of the issue and the HTML is missing the element with the `.partner-logo-container` and the CSS making the images absolute, guessing the missing parts I can see the code works fine, the only reason you don't see a fade is because it is only 250ms. If you increase it to 1000ms you will see the fade. ► https://jsfiddle.net/LtzLr1gv/ However, you are always targeting **all** images and not just the ones in each `col` so if you post your exact markup and css this might be easier to fix.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. I took the freedom to create a fiddle.

HTML

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
  <div class="partner-logo-container">


    <img class="image-without-color image" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/417/417715.svg" style="width: 200px">
    <img class="image-with-color image" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/417/417746.png" style="width: 200px">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <img class="image-without-color">
    <img class="image-with-color">
  </div>
</div>
```

javaScript

```
$('.partner-logo-container').hover(function(){
    $(".image-without-color", this).fadeOut(250);       
    $(".image-with-color", this).fadeIn(250);  
  }, function(){
    $(".image-with-color", this).fadeOut(250);   
    $(".image-without-color", this).fadeIn(250);
  }
);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/0402ds79/5/

Seems to work fine for me? Could you specify what went wrong at your end?

Greetings Chris

Comment: Thank you @kris. Maybe I have some conflict in the code. I'll try to debug it!

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".partner-logo-container").hover(function(){
        $(".image-without-color").fadeOut(3000, function(){
            $(".image-with-color").fadeIn(3000)
        });
    });
```

Comment: This will `hide`/`show` elements, not `fadeIn`/`fadeOut`?

Comment: Just "fadeOut" in place of "hide" and "fadeIn" in place of "show"

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score -1):

Ok, I feel ashamed. There was **some kind of problem with the browser** (Chrome). I restarted and it started working. Thank you all for your awesome solutions!

Just to help others. Uou should also add the **stop() before the fadOut**. This way it will stop the previous running animation.

**like this:**

```
$('.partner-logo-container').hover(
  function(){
    $(".image-without-color", this).stop().fadeOut(250);       
    $(".image-with-color", this).stop().fadeIn(250);  
  },
  function(){
    $(".image-with-color", this).stop().fadeOut(250);   
    $(".image-without-color", this).stop().fadeIn(250);
  }
);
```